# symmetrize matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, symmetric-matrices

If there are two square matrices $A$, $B$, will there be an invertible matrix $P$ such that $P^{-1}AP$ and $P^{-1}BP$ are symmetric matrices?  Or what condition do we need for $A,B$ to ensure such $P$ exists?

Comment: Symmetric matrices have real eigenvalues. Similar matrices have the same eigenvalues.

Comment: what if diag(1+i, 1-i)?

Comment: This is not a real entry matrix.

Comment: A and B may not be real entry matrices. All I want is there exists $P$ such that $P^{-1}AP$ and $P^{-1}BP$ are both symmetric matrices, and I don't know whether such matrix $P$ exists, or under what condition of $A,B$ to ensure such $P$ exists.  That is my question.

Comment: Then you should specify the field. For complex matrices, "symmetric" is rarely used, replaced by "Hermitian". There are many other fields too.

Comment: OK, now, let's say $A$ and $B$ are real matrices, then does such $P$ exist?

Comment: Of course, not. See my first comment.

Comment: The trivial case is that at least when $A$ and $B$ are symmetric, such $P$ exists ($P=I$). So then the question  would be under what condition of $A,B$?